# Cannot create Java List

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I want to use [this](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html) code and create JSF 2.0 table.

This is the Java Code of the Managed bean:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
// or import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
/* include SQL Packages */
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
// or import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean; 
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.model.DataModel;
import javax.faces.model.ListDataModel;

import org.glassfish.osgicdi.OSGiService;

@Named("ApplicationController")
@SessionScoped
public class Application implements Serializable {

    private List<Item> list;
    private transient DataModel<Item> model;
    private Item item = new Item();
    private boolean edit;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // list = dao.list();
        // Actually, you should retrieve the list from DAO. This is just for demo.
        list = new ArrayList<Item>();
        list.add(new Item(1L, "item1"));
        list.add(new Item(2L, "item2"));
        list.add(new Item(3L, "item3"));
    }

    public void add() {
        // dao.create(item);
        // Actually, the DAO should already have set the ID from DB. This is just for demo.
        item.setId(list.isEmpty() ? 1 : list.get(list.size() - 1).getId() + 1);
        list.add(item);
        item = new Item(); // Reset placeholder.
    }

    public void edit() {
        item = model.getRowData();
        edit = true;
    }

    public void save() {
        // dao.update(item);
        item = new Item(); // Reset placeholder.
        edit = false;
    }

    public void delete() {
        // dao.delete(item);
        list.remove(model.getRowData());
    }

    public List<Item> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public DataModel<Item> getModel() {
        if (model == null) {
            model = new ListDataModel<Item>(list);
        }

        return model;
    }

    public Item getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public boolean isEdit() {
        return edit;
    }

}
```

I get this problem when I import the code into Netbeans:

[image]
[image]

How I can declare the Java list in order to work?

Best wishes

EDIT I edited the code this way:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
// or import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
/* include SQL Packages */
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
// or import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean; 
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.model.DataModel;
import javax.faces.model.ListDataModel;

import org.glassfish.osgicdi.OSGiService;

@Named("ApplicationController")
@SessionScoped
public class Application implements Serializable {

    public Application() {
    }    

    private List<Application> list;
    private transient DataModel<Application> model;
    private Application item = new Application();
    private boolean edit;

    private Application(long l, String string) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // list = dao.list();
        // Actually, you should retrieve the list from DAO. This is just for demo.
        list = new ArrayList<Application>();
        list.add(new Application(1L, "item1"));
        list.add(new Application(2L, "item2"));
        list.add(new Application(3L, "item3"));
    }

    public void add() {
        // dao.create(item);
        // Actually, the DAO should already have set the ID from DB. This is just for demo.
        item.setId(list.isEmpty() ? 1 : list.get(list.size() - 1).getId() + 1);
        list.add(item);
        item = new Application(); // Reset placeholder.
    }

    public void edit() {
        item = model.getRowData();
        edit = true;
    }

    public void save() {
        // dao.update(item);
        item = new Application(); // Reset placeholder.
        edit = false;
    }

    public void delete() {
        // dao.delete(item);
        list.remove(model.getRowData());
    }

    public List<Application> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public DataModel<Application> getModel() {
        if (model == null) {
            model = new ListDataModel<Application>(list);
        }

        return model;
    }

    public Application getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public boolean isEdit() {
        return edit;
    }

    private void setId(int i) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    private int getId() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

}
```

Do you see any mistakes?

Comment: Hi, have you declared the right constructor for your Item-class?

Comment: I've updated my answer based on the question update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not focus on article's code examples only. Read the article's text as well. The text is not written for decoration only :)

> *The `Item` class is just a simple model object, its code should be straightforward enough. A `Serializable` Javabean with two properties `Long id` and `String value`, a default constructor and a constructor filling both properties, a bunch of appropriate getters/setters, `equals()` and `hashCode()` overriden.*

You can almost autogenerate it in its entirety with a bit decent IDE like Eclipse.

Answer (score 4):

You have to define the `Item` class.

UPDATE:

To keep the code in the first form. You should have a `Item` class.

```
public class Item {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    public Item() {}
    public Item(long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    //getters and setters for the attributes...
}
```

Now, in your updated code, you're using a list of `Application` objects. So your `Application` class should have 2 attributes of `long` and `String` type:

```
//annotations here...
public class Application implements Serializable {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    //getters and setters for these attributes...

    public Application() {
        //keep your actual code here
    }

    //we have to add a constructor that receives a long and a String
    //to initialize the attributes values.
    public Application(long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    //your actual code...
}
```

Second option is not a good practice, I recommend you separate the Backing Bean (Managed Bean) class from your model classes (in this case, the Item class).

Answer (score 2):

From [this version](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/mail/FetchProfile.Item.html) of the API, the *Item* constructor requires a String parameter, which you are not providing. I think your IDE has pulled in that class by accident.

Reading the example from the link in the question I believe you need to supply your own `Item` class (and import it correctly) which will need a no-argument constructor and one that takes a *long* and a *String*.